# Default index properties

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

What index would be created for this syntax?

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name ON table_name(column_name)
```

What type of index (clustured or non-clustered), would be created when we just write `create index`?

Comment: Homework? What version of SQL are you using? What exactly are you stuck on understanding?

Comment: Tag the dbms used, and perhaps we will understand the question.

Comment: Well, it would create an index named `IDX_NAME` on a column named `Column_name` in a table named `TABLE`.  You can literally just read the syntax and answer your question.

Comment: SQL SERVER 2012. My question is what type of index(clustured or non clustered) would be created when we just pass create index

Answer (score 2):

Without a type specified, the default is `NONCLUSTERED`.

[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx)

> -- Create a nonclustered index on a table or view
>   CREATE INDEX i1 ON t1 (col1);
>
> ---
>
> If CLUSTERED is not specified, a nonclustered index is created.